# Lambda Authorizer fails with invalid token after generating using apigClientFactory

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

This is within a VUE project using VUEX.

The aim is to be able to control access to the API Gateway for both authenticated users and unauthenticated users.

In my Identity pool I can see that both authenticated and unauthenticated users are being picked up but I cannot get the Authorizer to accept the token that the SDK (aws-api-gateway-client) generates.

First I am getting accessKeyId etc

```
let AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.region = env.aws.aws_cognito_region;

AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
  IdentityPoolId:
    env.aws.aws_cognito_region +
    ":" +
    env.aws.aws_cognito_identity_pool_id,
  Logins: {
    ["cognito-idp." +
    env.aws.aws_cognito_region +
    ".amazonaws.com/" +
    env.aws
      .aws_user_pools_id]: rootState.UserStore.authSession
      .getIdToken()
      .getJwtToken(),
  },
});

AWS.config.credentials.get(function() {
  commit("SET_ACCESS_CREDS", {
    updatedAt: new Date(),
    accessKeyId: AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey,
    sessionToken: AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken,
  });
});
```

These credentials looks good.  I can output them and am happy they don't look broken.

Then I try to use these to access the api gateway using apigClientFactory.newClient

```
var apigClientFactory = require("aws-api-gateway-client").default;

var client = apigClientFactory.newClient({
  accessKey: state.AccessCredentials.accessKeyId,
  secretKey: state.AccessCredentials.secretAccessKey,
  sessionToken: state.AccessCredentials.sessionToken,
  region: env.aws.aws_cognito_region,
  invokeUrl: process.env.VUE_APP_APIBASEURL,
});
console.log(client);
client.invokeApi({}, "/testauth", "GET").then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

My understanding here is that the SDK takes those values and generates what it needs to send to the API.  I've read about it's algorithm, I don't understand it entirely but it implies it creates the access token and wraps it into a request.

The route `testauth` has the authorizer assigned.

The code for the authorizer is from the AWS doc

```
// A simple token-based authorizer example to demonstrate how to use an authorization token 
// to allow or deny a request. In this example, the caller named 'user' is allowed to invoke 
// a request if the client-supplied token value is 'allow'. The caller is not allowed to invoke 
// the request if the token value is 'deny'. If the token value is 'unauthorized' or an empty
// string, the authorizer function returns an HTTP 401 status code. For any other token value, 
// the authorizer returns an HTTP 500 status code. 
// Note that token values are case-sensitive.

exports.handler =  function(event, context, callback) {
    var token = event.authorizationToken;
    switch (token) {
        case 'allow':
            callback(null, generatePolicy('user', 'Allow', event.methodArn));
            break;
        case 'deny':
            callback(null, generatePolicy('user', 'Deny', event.methodArn));
            break;
        case 'unauthorized':
            callback("Unauthorized");   // Return a 401 Unauthorized response
            break;
        default:
            callback("Error: Invalid token"); // Return a 500 Invalid token response
    }
};

// Help function to generate an IAM policy
var generatePolicy = function(principalId, effect, resource) {
    var authResponse = {};
    
    authResponse.principalId = principalId;
    if (effect && resource) {
        var policyDocument = {};
        policyDocument.Version = '2012-10-17'; 
        policyDocument.Statement = [];
        var statementOne = {};
        statementOne.Action = 'execute-api:Invoke'; 
        statementOne.Effect = effect;
        statementOne.Resource = resource;
        policyDocument.Statement[0] = statementOne;
        authResponse.policyDocument = policyDocument;
    }
    
    // Optional output with custom properties of the String, Number or Boolean type.
    authResponse.context = {
        "stringKey": "stringval",
        "numberKey": 123,
        "booleanKey": true
    };
    return authResponse;
}
```

The cloudwatch logs for the authorizer say "Invalid token".

I don't see how it could be anything but that because all it's doing it just seems to be asking if the token says "allow" which seems a bit strange.

Am I by chance just using the wrong function to generate the token in this case?

It's surprising there isn't a comprehensive documentation on this type of requirement as it seems pretty standard.

Comment: PS Willing to accept I need a whole new approach - this is all put together by scavenging around different websites

Comment: I strongly think I need to find another authorizer but also can't help but notice that I keep seeing online that the format in the header needing to be `Authorisation: bearer XXX...` where as the above skips instead uses `AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=XXX/us-east-1/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=accept;host;x-amz-date, Signature=XXX`

Answer (score 0):

In the end I am just validating the JWT token from Cognito which I got from here:

https://blog.mantalus.com/posts/apigw-custom-authorizer-cognito/

I do not use the API SDK